# how to draw ECG like graph in asp.net c#.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph

how to draw ECG like graph in asp.net c#.I have array of String which I stored ECG values. I just want to display them in an ECG like Graph.

```
    string will be like as follows:
    string [] s=new string(0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0,64,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use MSChart.  This gives you chart control similar to what is used in Excel.

Here is an example from [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETChart-9e45b8d1).

Comment: Mr.@David Setty. Thank you for the suggestion .But I tried that control. Every 10 seconds my page  will get refresh. So the asp.net chart control blinks every 10 seconds. I don't want it to bilnk. Then I put Chart to an update panel . But it still blinks. Is there any way to plot ECG graph?